# postgresql running in docker compose doesn't create role

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run postgreSQL via docker-compose and I am getting the issue that user/password is not created when I started the service.

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    #volumes:
      #- postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgrespassword
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=random_db_name
    restart: always
```

I have this block of code in my docker-compose.yml and I run the following command:
docker-compose up -d  (this allow me to start the service in background)

and when I check the logs I got:

```
docker logs -f 0e1731f95396                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok


Success. You can now start the database server using:

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

waiting for server to start....2021-04-27 16:20:44.592 UTC [49] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2021-04-27 16:20:44.594 UTC [49] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-04-27 16:20:44.603 UTC [50] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-04-27 16:20:44 UTC
2021-04-27 16:20:44.609 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

waiting for server to shut down...2021-04-27 16:20:44.889 UTC [49] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
.2021-04-27 16:20:44.891 UTC [49] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-04-27 16:20:44.892 UTC [49] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 56) exited with exit code 1
2021-04-27 16:20:44.892 UTC [51] LOG:  shutting down
2021-04-27 16:20:44.907 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2021-04-27 16:20:45.018 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2021-04-27 16:20:45.019 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-04-27 16:20:45.019 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-04-27 16:20:45.023 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-04-27 16:20:45.029 UTC [77] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-04-27 16:20:44 UTC
2021-04-27 16:20:45.034 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

But when I try to connect to this database locally I get the message: "FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist"

**Do you have any input about how to solve this problem?
I already made a few attempts after reading a few comments from different places but I got always the same problem.**

I was expecting to run locally postgreSQL and setup already a user/password and a Database with that name in the docker-compose

Comment: What command are you using to connect?

Comment: I am using 
host: localhost
port: 5432

user: postgres
password: postgrespassword
database: random_db_name


When I am trying to access I got the error above.. I was expecting to use these values and be able to connect to this table